Actions and consequences
Lyxism
The main principle of my philosophy is that every action taken by a rational being has consequences. An idea is an action that implies consequences and has meaning that can be expressed in words. The value of ideas is determined by how beneficial these consequences are for the subject. Examples:
"I killed a person because I wanted to." Here, we see that the subject performed an action, which is expressed as killing, but we don't have additional information about what exactly led to this result or what the idea was. Therefore, we are unable to assess the meaning of the action. However, we can assess the value of the action even without an idea: the value of this action is negative from start to finish, as the killing had no purpose. Consequently, this person will go to jail, and no benefit can come from it. However, there is too little information; additional information could give this action meaning and, therefore, an idea.
I want you to look at this skeptically: perhaps my thoughts have already been used, it's nonsense, or something similar. I want to understand whether I need to continue developing this philosophy or not.

I think that reason, ideas and Philosophy should be a last resort. Pursue other things first.

The "Ethical egoism" article on Wikipedia directly answers your question, particularly in the "Criticism" section.

what is your question?
